# How do I get my discord bot to play music from YouTube (without link)?

Tags: npm, youtube-api, discord.js, node-cron, post-install

I'm very new to this.

I've made a bot for discord and now i want it to play music from YouTube, without having to put in a link.

I'm using Heroku and am getting several errors, that I really need help with.

I have tried pushing it several times, but I'm unsure what else can do.

[image: Error when pushing heroku]

[image: When i try searching for a youtube song]

[Dynos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9mLp.png)

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Comment: @stvar I'm only using cmd, git bash and heroku. Made the bot in discord bot maker. I'm not familiar with any other programs, so i'm unsure how to post this differently?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have forgotten to write the dyno to tell Heroku what to run. Try adding a Procfile to your project and name it "worker: node index.js". From what I understand, your second message says "missing script: start".

Comment: i already have a Procfile with "worker: node bot.js. Should i Edit that or make another?

Comment: Is that procfile active? Is it turned on in the dynos?

Comment: In heroku you mean? It says the bot is running.

Comment: I added a picture of it in the question